# upload multiple images using symfony

Tags: php, html, symfony

I'd like to upload a lot of photos from HTMLto my symfony server. I don't know why but it doesn't work.

```
<form method="post" action="/api/photographer/photos/up">
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
        Selecciona tus fotos 
        <input id="photos" idenctype="multipart/form-data" type="file" name="photos[]" multiple="multiple" >
    </span>

    <button id="uploader" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> 
        S&uacute;belas al servidor
    </button>
</form>
```

symfony:

```
function upPhotosAction(Request $request){
    $photos = $request->files->get('photos');
    var_dump($photos);
    return "ok";
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as a form attribute:

```
<form method="post" action="/api/photographer/photos/up" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```